# C Program not running as intended, hangs after input

Tags: c, arrays, user-input

The program I am writing to take a number and display that number as a calculator would display it (shown below) is compiling with no issues, but when I try to run it, I am able to input my number, but nothing happens. It seems like it is "hanging", since no further output is shown as I would have expected. Might anyone know what the problem is?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAX_DIGITS 20

char segments[10][7] =              /* seven segment array */
    {{'1','1','1','1','1','1','0'}, /* zero */
     {'0','1','1','0','0','0','0'}, /* one */
     {'1','1','0','1','1','0','1'}, /* two */
     {'1','1','1','1','0','0','1'}, /* three */
     {'0','1','1','0','0','1','1'}, /* four */
     {'1','0','1','1','0','1','1'}, /* five */
     {'1','0','1','1','1','1','1'}, /* six */
     {'1','1','1','0','0','0','0'}, /* seven */
     {'1','1','1','1','1','1','1'}, /* eight */
     {'1','1','1','0','0','1','1'}};/* nine */
char digits[3][MAX_DIGITS * 4];     /* digits array */
int i, j;                           /* count variables */
int adjust;                         /* output formatting */

int main(void) {
    clear_digits_array();

    int digit[20];
    for (i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        digit[i] = 0;
    }

    int count = 20;
    int position = 0;

    printf("Enter a number: ");

    int number = scanf("%d%d%d%d%d%d%d%d%d%d%d%d%d%d%d%d%d%d%d%d",
            &digit[0],
            &digit[1],
            &digit[2],
            &digit[3],
            &digit[4],
            &digit[5],
            &digit[6],
            &digit[7],
            &digit[8],
            &digit[9],
            &digit[10],
            &digit[11],
            &digit[12],
            &digit[13],
            &digit[14],
            &digit[15],
            &digit[16],
            &digit[17],
            &digit[18],
            &digit[19]);                        //NOTHING HAPPENS AFTER HERE

    printf("Got input, number is %d", number); 

    while (count > 0) {
        printf("Reading digits, count is %d", count);
        process_digit(digit[20 - count], position);
        position++;
        count--;
    }

    print_digits_array();
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}

void clear_digits_array(void) {
    /* fill all positions in digits array with blank spaces */
    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < (MAX_DIGITS * 4); j++) {
            digits[i][j] = ' ';
        }
    }
}

void process_digit(int digit, int position) {
    /* check each segment to see if segment should be filled in for given digit */
    for (i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
        printf("Processing digit %d at position %d, i is %d", digit, position, i);
        if (segments[digit][i] == 1) {
            switch (i) {
                case 0: digits[0][(position * 4) + 1] = '_';
                        break;
                case 1: digits[1][(position * 4) + 2] = '|';
                        break;
                case 2: digits[2][(position * 4) + 2] = '|';
                        break;
                case 3: digits[2][(position * 4) + 1] = '_';
                        break;
                case 4: digits[2][(position * 4) + 0] = '|';
                        break;
                case 5: digits[1][(position * 4) + 0] = '|';
                        break;
                case 6: digits[1][(position * 4) + 1] = '_';
                        break;
            }
        }
    }
}

void print_digits_array(void) {
    /* print each character in digits array */
    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < (MAX_DIGITS * 4); j++) {
            printf("%c", digits[i][j]);
        }
        printf("/n");
    }
}
```

Comment: Its working like it should, may be you're missing something while entering numbers.

Comment: I assure you, it isn't working like it should...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code includes:

```
printf("Enter a number: ");

int number = scanf("%d%d%d%d%d%d%d%d%d%d%d%d%d%d%d%d%d%d%d%d",
        &digit[0],
        &digit[1],
        &digit[2],
        &digit[3],
        &digit[4],
        &digit[5],
        &digit[6],
        &digit[7],
        &digit[8],
        &digit[9],
        &digit[10],
        &digit[11],
        &digit[12],
        &digit[13],
        &digit[14],
        &digit[15],
        &digit[16],
        &digit[17],
        &digit[18],
        &digit[19]);                        //NOTHING HAPPENS AFTER HERE
```

Have you entered twenty separate digits?  If not, `scanf()` is waiting for you to type some more numbers.

Note that the return value from `scanf()` is the number of successfully converted numbers (0..20 in the example), not the value you entered.

---

> Is that the issue? I tried to make it such that the maximum amount of numbers the user could enter was 20, and if any more were entered they would be ignored, or if fewer were entered, it would only consider those (say, 5 were entered, then only the 5 would be used). Is there an easier way to do this sort of thing then?

Yes, I think that's the issue.

There are probably several easier ways to do it.  I'd be tempted to use:

```
char buffer[22];  // 20 digits, newline, null
if (fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), stdin) != EOF)
{
    size_t len = strlen(buffer);
    if (len >= sizeof(buffer) - 1)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "You entered too long a string (maximum 20 digits)\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    if (len > 0)
        buffer[--len] = '\0';  // Zap newline — carefully
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        if (!isdigit(buffer[i]))
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Non-digit %c found\n", buffer[i]);
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }
    ...and from here, process the digits in buffer, one at a time...
    ...Use buffer[i] - '0' to get a number 0..9 from the character in buffer...
}
```

Another option is to use a `long long` number, but that only gives you up to 18 digits (signed) or 19 digits (unsigned), with some values of 19 or 20 also within range.  You'd then strip the digits out of the number using division and modulus operations.

```
long long value;
if (scanf("%lld", &value) == 1)
{
    if (value < 0)
        ...error processing...
    do
    {
        int digit = value % 10;
        value /= 10;
        ...process digit...
    } while (value > 0);
}
```

This has some merits, but in practice, I'd be tempted to use `fgets()` to read a line of input, and either `sscanf()` or  `strtoll()` to convert and validate the number.  That isn't as simple as it looks; the error returns from `strtoll()`, in particular, are many and subtle, and none of the `scanf()` family handle overflowing numbers gracefully. You could constrain the `scanf()` though with `%18lld` so that no more than 18 digits are read, but that would mean that if the user typed 19 or more digits, you'd get the leftovers on the next attempt to read with `scanf()`. So, handling `scanf()` is not simple either, especially if you need to convert multiple numbers in a single run of the program.

With those caveats out of the way, you can usually do a 'good enough' job with a sensible person providing the input.  It is the process of making a program bomb-proof (foolproof — as in, proof against fools) that is hard.  I find meaningful error reporting easier when I can report the whole string that was read in (as with `fgets()`); with `scanf()`, you can't see the characters that were entered and consumed before something went wrong.

Comment: Is that the issue? I tried to make it such that the maximum amount of numbers the user could enter was 20, and if any more were entered they would be ignored, or if fewer were entered, it would only consider those (say, 5 were entered, then only the 5 would be used). Is there an easier way to do this sort of thing then?

Comment: Thanks very much for the detailed help and answer! I appreciate it. However, there is one more issue. Now, everything runs well, but the output at the very end (the segment display) does not display at all. There are just blank spaces. Why might this be?

Comment: I've not looked at that code, but I'd have to guess you aren't handling the conversion of digits entered by the user into strings for printing correctly.  That part is for you to debug at this point. Maybe you should think about encoding the `segments` array with the character to be printed (`|`, `_`, or ` ` (blank)) so you don't need the switch to map characters.

Comment: One observation for you; the variables `i` and `j` should not be global; they should be declared in the loop as they are used: `for (int i = 0; i < X; i++)`, etc.  If you changed your diagnostic print in `process_digit()` to: `printf("Processing digit %d at position %d, i is %d (segment[digit][i] = %d)\n", digit, position, i, segments[digit][i]);` you'd quickly see why the `if` around the `switch` is not working properly.  Also, note that `"/n"` is a two character string, not a single character string containing a newline. Fix the `if` and deal with the data entry and your program works.

Answer (score 0):

use GDB, here is introduction for it http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/
look into this tutorial too http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~gilpin/tutorial/

Answer (score 0):

```
int number = scanf("%d%d%d%d%d%d%d%d%d%d%d%d%d%d%d%d%d%d%d%d",
            &digit[0],
            &digit[1],
            &digit[2],
            &digit[3],
            &digit[4],
            &digit[5],
            &digit[6],
            &digit[7],
            &digit[8],
            &digit[9],
            &digit[10],
            &digit[11],
            &digit[12],
            &digit[13],
            &digit[14],
            &digit[15],
            &digit[16],
            &digit[17],
            &digit[18],
            &digit[19]);
```

I don't think this is a good idea use `loop` here

```
for (i = 0; i < 20; i++) 
        scanf("%d",&digit[i]);
```

And if you need the `number`
then do like this

`int number = i;` when loop finishes.

You can also try this

```
char buf[12]; 
while((c=getchar())!=EOF && i < 20)
{
 buf[j++] =c;
 if((c == '\n' || c == ' ' || c == '\t') && (sscanf(buf,"%d",&digit[i])) == 1)
   {
    i++;
    j = 0;
   }
 }
```

For EOF you will have to press `CTRL+D`
In this way you can take 20 or less integers